# python, run win cm line many quotes for command line with arguments

Tags: cmd, subprocess, popen, double-quotes

The following command line (assigned to the var "cmdlin4popup") runs just fine when I paste it into a Windows cmd.exe (terminal?) window:

```
"E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\inputBox wscript.popup_aaa.vbs" "E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141045__Tmp_7602977475348411.py_.txt" 9 "Backup Report" 65
```

But subprocess.Popen(cmdlin4popup) triggers an error message:

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I think that the problem is the placement of quotes, i.e., the number of double quotes and their placement, but I can't figure out what Python needs.  I'd appreciate any suggestions about where to find the solution.

None of the following alternate placements of quotes ran successfully:

```
cmdlin4popup = "E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\inputBox wscript.popup_aaa.vbs" "E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141059__Tmp_2248283756147461.py_.txt" 9 "Backup Report" 65

cmdlin4popup = """E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\inputBox wscript.popup_aaa.vbs" E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141059__Tmp_2248283756147461.py_.txt 9 "Backup Report" 65"""

cmdlin4popup = "E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\inputBox wscript.popup_aaa.vbs" "E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141059__Tmp_2248283756147461.py_.txt 9 "Backup Report" 65"

cmdlin4popup = "E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\inputBox wscript.popup_aaa.vbs" """E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141059__Tmp_2248283756147461.py_.txt 9 "Backup Report" 65"""
```

I am pretty sure that I tried all of the following alternate methods to run each of the above command lines, again with no success:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmdlin4popup)
subprocess.run(cmdlin4popup)
subprocess.call(cmdlin4popup)
os.startfile(cmdlin4popup)
```

If the solution was in either of the following postings, I didn't understand the solutions: [Python run command line (time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662852/python-run-command-line-time), [Command line passing quotes within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484428/command-line-passing-quotes-within-quotes)

As an interim kludge workaround (FYI for anyone else dealing with this problem), I wrote the cmdlin4popup var's value to a text file with the extension '.cmd', and successfully used subprocess.run (as recommended by Bill Horvath):

```
ret_val = subprocess.run(cmdlin4popup)
```

But it would be great to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen` expects a list. And if you have to have the double-quotes to make it work, add single-quotes around them:

```
cmdlin4popup = ['"E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\inputBox wscript.popup_aaa.vbs"', '"E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141045__Tmp_7602977475348411.py_.txt"', 9, '"Backup Report"', 65]
```

Also, consider using `subprocess.run` instead, which is [recommended in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Comment: I tried subprocess.run(cmdlin4popup) using your string modifications, but I got the following error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: That suggests one of the files is missing. It looks like you're referencing two file locations, `wscript.popup_aaa.vbs` and `E:\Zmani\Logging\202212141045__Tmp_7602977475348411.py_.txt`. The first one should be in the same directory in which you're executing the python script. Are either of those missing on the machine you're running this on?

Comment: First, thank you for your efforts.  Neither of the files is missing.  I don't see why the 2 files should be or need to be in the same directory, since my original cmdlin4popup var's value runs successfully when I write it to a file "cmdlin4popup.cmd" and then invoke subprocess.run(cmdlin4popup).

Comment: We may be running up against the limits of my knowledge of running python in a Windows environment here. For example: to construct a path that I'll use in a subprocess, I'd usually `from pathlib import Path`, then `my_path = Path("E", "Apps", "UtilitiesByMarc", "inputBox")`, with `my_path` then passed as an argument to `subprocess`. That provides a largely platform-independent approach to path construction, meaning I don't have to worry about which OS I'm in, but it also means I don't have enough experience specifying paths directly in python on Windows to say what's happening for sure.